# How to extract data from Ng Multiselect dropdown to from group

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I'm using Ng Multiselect Dropdown to select multiple data everything is working perfectly but I am facing issue with one thing and that is when users submits the data the data is uploaded but select option from drop down is stored like this [object] rather it should be stored with the selected option name

it is an issue with array decode can any one help me, below I have even shared the screenshot for the same

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is [object Object] showing? Is it a html table?

Comment: [object Object] is getting stored in database but i want to store the name of selected item its is selecting the whole array

Comment: you can check on the first pick for reference

Comment: Share code where you are uploading data

Comment: Can you provide your code on stackblitz.com to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am so sorry but I cant share my code due to my comapny norms, if ossible can anyone help me how to decode an array i just saw the structure of database it is storing the data in array format how can i decode it when i am calling for an eg : we write {{data.client}} now there is and array stored in client where its item_name and i want that value

Comment: I am attaching the screenshot by editing question above pls check the last image

Comment: Try using map to format the array and convert to sting ``` (client.map(x=> x.item_text)).join(',')``` before submitting the form

Comment: can you please guide me how can i do that as I am new to this

Comment: try like this before submitting (client.map(x=> x.item_text)).join(','). or you can stringify and save to db JSON.stringify(client)

Comment: @JunedAdenwalla What type of data do you want when selected uisng dropdown ?

Comment: It would be possible to JSON pipe the data. `data="(dropdownClient | json)"` `[(ngModel)]="(selectedItemsClient | json)"`.

Comment: If you just need the text field then replace the ```dropdownClient``` as array of strings, like ```[ 'client_1', 'client_2']```, this will store the data as array of string not array of object

Comment: I got the solution for this {{ customer.client[0].item_text }}, but now it is only giving me the first entry how can i get get all the data in short what should i use besides 0 to get all data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is all about how to iterate over your array of objects to view your objects properly, for example, if you have such data:

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {
    checked: false,
    position: 1,
    item: [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Item1' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Item2' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Item3' },
    ],
  },
  {
    checked: false,
    position: 2,
    item: [
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Item4' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'Item5' },
      { item_id: 6, item_text: 'Item6' },
    ],
  },
];
```

Then you can iterate over `item` array as follows:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="item">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Item </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let i of element.item">
          {{i.item_id}} , {{i.item_text}}
          <br>
          <br>
      </ng-container>
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And these objects will be displayed like below:

[image]

Here is a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hero-form-as-form-group-yzfwav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: hey that helped a lot this is what i was looking for thank you, but last question its is giving me output vertically i want it one below another how can i do it

Comment: You're welcome, I don't get your question, I think if you want it one below another, this will be considered vertically, or do you want them horizontally?  I think you can remove `<br>` tag and see if this is what you're looking for, or maybe explain more so I can help

Comment: hello, do you have idea if the data output has more than 3 word it should show its count next to it when three words end how can i do this

Comment: Yes sure, you can add `*ngIf` condition to do this. I've modified the code in the link above, please check it and tell me if that is what are you looking for or not.

Comment: If I misunderstood you, please post another question with a pic and more details, then send the link here and I'll try to help.